# Metodo en java no Funciona

Tags: java

Tengo un método en el que recorro un arreglo de char, lo que necesito es recorrer el arreglo y cuando encuentre el carácter que busco sume un contador, el método ingresa pero no se cumple la condición de cuando el contador tiene un cierto numero imprima un mensaje y salga del método.

Aqui mi código:

```
public class Tablero {

 public static void validarColumna(char array[][]) {
            int contx = 0;
            int conty = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == 'X') {

                    contx++;
                    conty =0;
                    if (contx == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Linea!! Ganador Jugador 1");
                        return;
                    }
                }else if (array[i][j] == 'Y') {

                    conty++;
                    contx=0;
                    if (conty == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Linea!! Ganador Jugador 1");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: y si usas el break en vez de return, y luego al final del método poner sólo return?

Comment: Sospecho demasiado de conty=0 y contx=0. Mejor iguala a cero una de esas variables cuando haya un ganador, ya sabes, hacer conty=0 cuando contx==4 o contx=0 cuando conty==4.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría dejar el código de la siguiente manera y mas abajo te lo intentare explicar a mi forma de ver:

```
public class Tablero {

public static void validarColumna(char array[][]) {
        int contx = 0;
        int conty = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 'X') {

                contx++;
                if (contx == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Linea!! Ganador Jugador 1");
                    return;
                }
            }else if (array[i][j] == 'Y') {

                conty++;
                if (conty == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Linea!! Ganador Jugador 1");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

he eliminado las lineas de 
    `contx=0;`
    `conty=0;`

por que con estas líneas lo que estas haciendo es que cada vez que este jugador haga un punto el otro se ponga a cero, es decir para ganar un jugador tiene que hacer 4 puntos seguidos sin que el otro puntúe, ya que cada vez que haces el `contx=0` o `conty=0` reseteas las puntuaciones sin que haya terminado el método.

en cuanto a los `return` puedes usar un `break` si prefieres, pero sería lo mismo ya que es una función de tipo `void`y nunca devolverá nada, ya es como prefieras tú.